# How to extract directory address from a list view?

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Using CodedUI, I have to verify the default save location of a file. In the dialog box, the save location is shown as

[image]

I need to read the address as My Documents\RobotStudio\Systems\CuttingPPTest\HOME\LsCuttingParamTables\

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected WinTreeItem then make a loop that goes through its ParentNodes. Get the name of each node and concat them into a string.